# FS2 Queue Producer and Consumer

Tags: scala, fs2

I used `fs2.concurrent.Queue` to try out Producer/Consumer via a queue.

```
val program = fs2.Stream.eval(Queue.bounded[IO, Option[Int]](maxSlots)).flatMap {
      q =>
        val p = customers[IO](10.millis, 100.millis, openingSeconds).evalMap(writeToQueue[IO](q))
        val c = q.dequeue.unNoneTerminate.parEvalMap(maxBarbers)(barbers[IO](300.millis, 100.millis))
        c concurrently p
    }
```

The solution I am using now is `p` will stop producing `Some(id)`, where id is customer's id, after `openingSeconds` and change to a Stream of `None` to terminate `c` i.e. `q.dequeue.unNoneTerminate`.

Can I use a single `None` instead of a repeating stream of `None` to terminate `c`?

The problem I faced with single `None` was when the queue `q` was full, the single `None` would not be inserted into the queue because `writeToQueue` would not accept new elements when the queue was full. `p` and `c` produced and consumed at a different rate. Thanks

Comment: It is totally normal that producers and consumers work in a different rate. What do you want to happen when queue is full?

Comment: when the queue is full, it will reject new ids until an empty slot is available. I have this in place. The problem is when the queue is full and the producer comes to an end. The final `None` is rejected from the queue and the consumer will never get the None unless I do a `Stream.repeatEval(Sync[F].pure(None))` at the end

Comment: How you enqueue items? There is [enqueue1](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/96e20dda096629ebddd06b4a18fe0f001365a0d4/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/concurrent/Queue.scala#L18) which blocks until it can enqueue item instead of dropping it.

Comment: I’m using offer1. When it returns false, I’ll discard the element and go for next.

Comment: You can always change the behavior - use `offer1` until list of items to insert is empty and then put `None` using `enqueue1`

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok your suggestion solved my question. Thanks